# Intriguing Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, 3d, diagonalization, tridiagonal-matrices

Given a positive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^N$, please consider the matrix

$$  \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & -a_1 & & & &   \\ 
-a_1 & a_2 + a_1 & -a_2 & & & \\ 
 & - a_2 & a_3 + a_2 & \ddots & &   \\ 
 & & \ddots& \ddots & \ddots  &    \\ 
 & & & \ddots & a_{N-1} + a_{N-2}&  -a_{N-1}  \\ 
 & & & & -a_{N-1}&  a_{N-1}  
\end{bmatrix}$$

where blank areas denote null matrix elements.

Does this type of matrix have a name, or resembles others from contexts you know of?

It is real, symmetric, tridiagonal. All its rows sum to zero. All its columns sum to zero as well. Can anything nontrivial be said on its eigenvalues?

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that the kernel is one-dimensional, generated by the vector $(1,1,\ldots$).

In the 3d case, I see that the nonzero eigenvalues are simply $a_1 + a_2 \pm \sqrt{a_1^2 - a_1 a_2 + a_2^2}$. So I am trying to guess a generalization of this formula - of which several come to mind. But there may be smarter way to go about it?

Thank you very much for any tip you may have.

Comment: In fact, if rows and columns of a tridiagonal matrix sum to the same constant value, the matrix must necessarily be symmetric.

Comment: Also, you can write your matrix as $I-S$, where $I$ is the identity and $S$ is doubly stochastic.

Comment: Not sure if this helps.

Comment: The point of @golfer can be relevant as matrices of the form $I-S$, with $S$ nonnegative, are extensively studied and known as M-matrices or Z-matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as the rank, that is indeed $n-1.$

Your matrix is of the form $Q^T D Q$  where

$$
D=
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & b & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

and

$$ Q =
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

This relationship is called congruence rather than similarity. [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) says that there are thus $n-1$  positive eigenvalues  and a single zero eigenvalue.   Note that $Q^T DQ$   is the proper way to change basis for a quadratic form.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I thought but couldn't prove.